# Is there a way to check which column is a duplicate when entering data into a table with unique properties (sqlalchemy)

Tags: database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a users table with:

```
id: number
username: unique string
password: string
email: unique string
first_name: string
last_name: string
...
```

Recently I tried to register with a user which has the same username as an already entered one and got an error. I tried to catch it as an `IntegrityError` exception but couldn't find any information regarding WHICH column is a duplicate in order to inform the user if it is the username, email or something else.

Is there any way to do this short of performing a query on all unique keys and seeing if they return something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to differentiate causes of SQLAlchemy's IntegrityError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65189213/how-to-differentiate-causes-of-sqlalchemys-integrityerror)

Answer (score 1):

you can read the msg within the IntegrityError Exception

```
except IntegretyError as e:
    if "username" in e.message:
        pass
```

Comment: I thought of that but there is a case where `name` could be unique and `username` could be unique. Therefore if you check if `"name" in e.message`, you are checking for both `username` and `name`. The only way to solve this would be by carefully adding all unique keys in an array in a manner where all the keys which contain other keys in their name are at the start of the array. Isn't really all that dynamic. I suppose I can create a function that sorts that out for me but that is worst case scenario, there must be a way to see which column is breaking the uniqueness integrity o the table.

Comment: you can do elif "name" in e.message: